# Do crontab entries persist permanently in EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

For example, if an EC2 instance is automatically rebooted by the system due to environment updates, do they persist? Is crontab by itself a safe measure to run repetitive tasks indefinitely, or do I need to apply something more(e.g. fstab)?

Sorry for the short description but thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have properly set up your Crontab, then a reboot will not loose your Crontab tasks or configuration.

However, you will want to take an AMI image of your system to save the Crontab settings so that you can create a new instance if needed, and have the same working Crontab configuration.

Alternatively, you can script your Crontab configuration as part of a Userdata configuration script. This will insure that any new instance is configured to your requirements.